# Spelling of numbers and particle "and"

Tags: grammar, orthography, numbers

I know that in order to spell a number you have to insert an "and" between the hundred and units. For instance 301 will be *"three hundred **and** one"*. But what about larger numbers?
1,301 is "one thousand three hundred and one"
or
*"one thousand **and** three hundred **and** one"*?

In this case, are British and American spellings the same?

Comment: Not really an answer to your question, but students of mathematics are instructed that _and_ only replaces the decimal point, so 1301 is "one thousand three hundred one"; 1301.5 is "one thousand three hundred one and a half".

Comment: @Malvolio Perhaps _some_ students of mathematics are. The ones who study math rather than maths.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One thousand three hundred and one is the correct way to say it in both American and British English.

Comment: Five million, three hundred seventy-two thousand four hundred and thirty five.

Comment: Five million, three hundred **and** seventy-two thousand four hundred and thirty five in British English. *And* is never omitted after *hundred*.